# I can not connect to the database by starting the jetty9

Tags: java, jsp

I have this error and I do not understand why nor how to solve it. What is DataSource?

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException:
>   `jdbc/db1' is an unknown DataSource   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.reservas.general.general.modificarshuttle_jsp._jspService(modificarshuttle_jsp.java:407)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)

Comment: DataSource is some source of data ;-) This might be a database or an LDAP directory or something completely different. What's the JSP-page looking like?

Comment: the problem is in the beginning, no in the JSP is normal. the data base is a unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to config the jetty.xml file when you start the jetty .

The parameters are these :

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <New id="z" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/db1</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
           <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="defaultAutoCommit">false</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:postgresql://ipaddress:port/database?loglevel=0</Set>
            <Set name="username">user</Set>
            <Set name="password">password</Set>
     </New>
    </Arg>
   </New>
```

You may read the documentation about jetty :

```
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure the Jetty Server                                      -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- Documentation of this file format can be found at:              -->
<!-- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax        -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- Additional configuration files are available in $JETTY_HOME/etc -->
<!-- and can be mixed in.  For example:                              -->
<!--   java -jar start.jar etc/jetty-ssl.xml                         -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- See start.ini file for the default configuraton files           -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you have aquery like this

```
<sql:query var="var" dataSource="jdbc/db1">SELECT * FROM table_name
```

in your jsp file
,so you should define your datasource (connection of your database) in web.xml
like this

```
<resource-ref>
 <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTest</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

`

and define your database connection(name,url,and driver ) in your  context.xml under META-INF folder

```
 <New id="db1" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
 <Arg></Arg>
 <Arg>jdbc/db1</Arg>
 <Arg>
    <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
       <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename</Set>
       <Set name="User">user</Set>
       <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
    </New>
 </Arg>
</New>
```

this is taken from [Datesource example](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jndi-datasource-examples.html#mysql-pooled-datasource)

Comment: These definitions I have already set, and I still get the same error, thank you very much for your help but it has to be for another reason the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quiet sure about Jetty 9 server. I faced the same issue in Jetty 10 server, and later made it working by enabling jetty plus module.